# How to create Profile Data singleton class?

Tags: singleton

I want create singleton class But I don't know how?

Example:

```
class Singleton {
      Singleton singleton = null;
      public static Singleton getInstance()
      {
        if (singleton == null)
           singleton = new Singleton();
        return singleton;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add static before in the **singleton class.**

```
class Singleton {
      static Singleton singleton = null;
      public static Singleton getInstance()
      {
        if (singleton == null)
           singleton = new Singleton();
        return singleton;
      }
   }
```